# Id against refid validation in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

My scenario is below.

1. check ref-type is "bibr" then take the rid value "ref001"
2. check the rid value in ref-list or table-list elements 'ref' and 'table' ids
3. if it is present then the element name should be 'ref'

similarly reverse case

1. 'ref' element id value "ref001" value should be present in any one of the 'xref' element and its ref-type value should be 'bibr'

Similar case for table-list

However, my code works when rid contains a single value "ref001" when it comes to multiple values "ref003 tbl1" not matching properly.

My XML file is below:

```
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref001">Nb (XXXX)</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref003 tbl1">Nu (XXXX)</xref> 
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref002">Na (XXXX)</xref>
<xref ref-type="table" rid="tbl2">Nx (XXXX)</xref>
</p>
<ref-list>
<ref id="ref001">XXX</ref>
<ref id="ref002">YYY</ref>
<ref id="ref003">ZZZ</ref>
<ref-list>
<table-list>
<table id="tbl1">XXX</table>
<table id="tbl2">XXX</table>
</table-list>
```

MY XSL code is below:

```
<xsl:template name="ridcheck">
            <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*:xref[matches(@ref-type,'^(bibr)$','i') and 
               (id(@rid[not(matches(name(.),'^(ref)$','i'))])]|
               descendant::*:xref[not(matches(@ref-type,'^(bibr)$','i')) and (id(@rid) 
               [matches(name(.),'^(ref)$','i')])]">
                <message errtype="Error">Element 'xref' attribute 'xref-type' value matching 'bibr' must refer to a 'ref' element id and vice versa</message>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I could not follow your description. Please post a full working XSLT and the expected result - see: [mcve]. --- In general, I would suggest using a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to resolve cross-references.

Comment: As you use the `id` function for cross-referencing, is there a DTD and/or a schema declaring the ID type attributes? Also, it would help if you showed a sample output of failing and of successful cross-validation. For instance, that element `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref003 tbl1">Nu (XXXX)</xref>`, does the `tbl1` `@rid` reference match or fail (as there is a `table id="tbl1"` but part of your descriptions sounds as if there should be a `table-list/ref[@id = 'tbl1']`)?